# Invalid date in Mongo db query using Moment

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, momentjs

I have executed the below queries,

```
db.SBM_USER_DETAIL.aggregate([

    {
        $project: {
            join_date: moment('$JOIN_DATE').locale('es').tz("Asia/Kolkata").format()
        }
    }
])
```

but the result is,

"**Invalid date**"

It stored the value in mongo db is ""**JOIN_DATE" : ISODate("2017-01-30T18:30:00.000Z")**"

Why its coming as a "invalid date"?

I dont know my mistakes, please help me.

Comment: Yes Joe, I'm using the single quotes around **'$JOIN_DATE'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregate pipeline can't directly handle arbitrary javascript.  In your example, the `moment` functions are being called by the shell before the document fields are substituted, so the value is invalid.

To apply a javascript function a field in each document, use `.map`, like so:

```
db.SBM_USER_DETAIL.aggregate([

    {
        $project: {
            join_date: '$JOIN_DATE' 
        }
    }
]).map(
    function(d) {
       d.join_date = moment(d.join_date).locale('es').tz("Asia/Kolkata").format();
       return d
})
```

Comment: Awesome. its working fine what i expected. Thanks lot :)

Comment: How can i use the return value(join-date) inside the aggregation query??

Comment: That would really depend on what exactly you were trying to do.  Comments really don't have enough space to explain that, but if you would open a new question with the details I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: please answer me, here i asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949439/mongo-db-iso-format