# Mongo DB ISO format

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Based on the below query return result I want to filter the month and ther year.

For example I only want data for the month of March.

```
db.SBM_USER_DETAIL.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        join_date: '$JOIN_DATE' 
    }
}
]).map(
    function(d) {
       d.join_date = moment(d.join_date).locale('es').tz("Asia/Kolkata").format();
       return d
})
```

How to use the returned formatted value of *join_date* inside the MongoDB aggregation query?

Comment: To me (and probably to others too) it is not really clear what you are asking. You say you want to filter by month and year. Then you ask how to use the formatted value of  `join_date`. Do you meant you want to apply a filter on the returned `join_date` value by month and year ?

Comment: First of all sorry for that. Yes, i want to apply a filter on the returned join_date value by month and year.

Comment: Would you be so kind and explain if the the use of the `map` function is necessary? Is all you want in this query just being able to filter by date month and year ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's ISODate is very similar to the javascript Date class.  If you have a date range in the Kolkata timezone, and want to filter by that, instantiate a pair of Date objects to define the range, before running the find.

For this instance, to return all `join_date` values that fall within March 2017, converted to the Kolkata (UTC-07:00) timezone, filter for date greater than or equal to midnight March 1 and less than midnight April 1, then convert the results using moment:

```
var first = new Date("2017-03-01T00:00:00-07:00");
var last = new Date("2017-04-01T00:00:00-07:00");
db.SBM_USER_DETAIL.find(
    {join_date:{$gte: first, $lt: last}}, //filter based on join_date
    {join_date:1,_id:0}   // only return join_date, omit this if you need all fields
).map(
    function(d) {
        d.join_date = moment(d.join_date).locale('es').tz("Asia/Kolkata").format();
        return d;
    }
);
```